# UnicodeDecodeError in Django

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

i am having this issue: even if i added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top of my views.py, i am getting `UnicodeDecodeError`. how can i handle those german umlauts `ü,ö,ä` in my views? i am trying to send emails with german umlauts in its content.

please help me with this issue. i want that german umlauts are shown correctly in its original form. i can write `ä` like `ae`, but this is what i want to avoid.

i googled a lot, but couldnot find anything that helped me

**ERROR**:
**UnicodeDecodeError at /location-save/
('ascii', ' kannst Du  \n                diese Location einsehen. M\xc3\xb6glichkeiten zur Bearbeitung der Locations werden bald zur Verfuegung stehen. \n\n Herzliche Gruesse, \n Dein LocateYourDate Team', 55, 56, 'ordinal not in range(128)')**

**The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: en. M��glic**

Comment: Does your text editor actually use UTF-8?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, i am using aptana, i dont know about this, can i see this somewhere?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError has nothing to do with you using non-ascii characters in the file, but rather what you are doing with them. You need to show a complete error message as this can be caused by an infinite amount of different things.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. When I said error message, I meant traceback. It's 6am and I have had no coffee. My bad.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, :)). no problem. i will post the traceback also now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a UnicodeDecodeError because you are trying to convert a non-ascii string of bytes (called `str` in Python 2 and `bytes` in Python 3) to a Unicode string (called `Unicode` in Python 2 and `str` in Python 3) without specifying it's encoding.

It's not possible to be more helpful than that without a full traceback.

I will guess that you are using Python 2, and you did something like this:

```
mystring = 'Det här är ju helt omöjligt'
```

What you probably want is this:

```
mystring = u'Det här är ju helt omöjligt'
```

Note the u'', making it into a Unicode string.

Comment: thanks, please see my error message update in the question. what should i do now?

Comment: @doniyor: Well, you need to understand how Unicode works in Python, to be honest. So you need to read the documentation and maybe some helpful blogposts. Start with these two: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/ http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: very nice. great help. honestly, i am very lazy to read about encodings :(